# aligning UINavigationBar programmatically with other controls added through Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode

If I am pushing a view controller onto the NavController, is there a way when designing this view to have the controls line up correctly?

Here's the issue I'm having, I had to align the TableView and MapView like so to get it to show up properly when loaded into the navcontroller:

[image]

This seems wrong.  The mapview as you can see overlaps the tableview in the editor, but when it runs their lined up correctly.  If I raise the mapview to line up directly on top of the tableview, when run, theres a white gap between the two.  I realize the NavBar is pushing things down, or that's my guess.

Is there anything in the Utilities I can set to handle this?

Comment: try un checking auto layout option in IB

Comment: better to keep auto layout checked and learn to use auto layout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually tell the view controller to show a navigation bar in interface builder in the attributes inspector.

[image]

Comment: keep in mind @MarkW that this doesn't actually *do* anything; it just shows you where the navigation bar would be, so you can position things with a navigation bar in mind.

Comment: yeah I was loading it with a navbar/controller so everything was lining up but I couldn't find where you could set a placeholder for a tab or nav bar that would help you line up the controls.

Answer (score 0):

select your view, then in File Inspector, uncheck **Use Autolayout**. It may helps you.